# One to one relationship doesn't work

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, orm

Hibernate version - 5.3.4.Final, mysql-connector version - 8.0.12

I have one `@OneToOne` relationship between post and post content:

Post:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "postsInfo")
public class PostsInfo {


    private long postId;
    private String title;
    private java.util.Date createDate;
    private Integer views;
    private Collection<Tags> tagsPost;
    private PostContent postContent;
    private PostImage postImage;
    private UserInfo userInfo;
    private List<PostsComments> postsComments;

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "post_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public long getPostId() {
        return postId;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "title", nullable = false)
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "createDate", nullable = false)
    public java.util.Date getCreateDate() {
        return createDate;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "views")
    public Integer getViews() {
        return views;
    }

    public PostsInfo(){}

    public PostsInfo(String title, List<Tags> tagsPost) {
        this.title = title;
        this.tagsPost = tagsPost;
        this.createDate = new Date();
    }

    @Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "PostsTags",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "post_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "tag_id"))
    public Collection<Tags> getTagsPost() {
        return tagsPost;
    }

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "postsInfo", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    public PostContent getPostContent() {
        return postContent;
    }

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "postsInfo", orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    public PostImage getPostImage() {
        return this.postImage;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
    public UserInfo getUserInfo() {
        return userInfo;
    }

    @Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL)
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "postsInfo")
    public List<PostsComments> getPostsComments() {
        return postsComments;
    }
}
```

PostContent:

```
   @Entity
@Table(name = "postContent")
public class PostContent {
    private long postId;
    private String content;
    private String subtitle;
    private List<PostInsideImages> postInsideImages;
    private PostsInfo postsInfo;

    @GenericGenerator(name = "generator", strategy = "foreign",
    parameters = @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(name = "property", value = "postsInfo"))
    @Id @GeneratedValue(generator = "generator")
    @Column(name = "post_id")
    public long getPostId() {
        return postId;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "content")
    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "subtitle")
    public String getSubtitle() {
        return subtitle;
    }

    public PostContent(){}

    public PostContent(String subtitle ,String content) {
        this.content = content;
        this.subtitle = subtitle;
    }

    public PostContent(String subtitle, String content, List<PostInsideImages> postInsideImages) {
        this.content = content;
        this.subtitle = subtitle;
        this.postInsideImages = postInsideImages;
    }

    @OneToMany( cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "postContent")
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    public List<PostInsideImages> getPostInsideImages() {
        return postInsideImages;
    }

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    public PostsInfo getPostsInfo() {
        return postsInfo;
    }
}
```

I have been trying to make load of PostContent lazy, but nothing works.

I add to `@OneToOne` relationship fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false,

I add to hibernate.cfg.xml this property:

```
<property name="hibernate.enhancer.enableLazyInitialization">true</property>
```

and this maven plugin:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.hibernate.orm.tooling</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-enhance-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>5.3.4.Final</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <configuration>
                            <failOnError>true</failOnError>
                            <enableLazyInitialization>true</enableLazyInitialization>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>enhance</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

to enable bytecode Enhancement,

add `@LazyToOne(LazyToOneOption.NO_PROXY)`,

I try to change hibernate version (5.2, 5.1.10, 5.3.3, 5.3.1), but still hibernate load post content eager.

My code for get a post:

```
@Override
public PostsInfo getCommonPost(long id){
    return session.find(PostsInfo.class, id);
}
```

Hibernate sql:

```
    Hibernate: select postsinfo0_.post_id as post_id1_9_0_, postsinfo0_.createDate as createDa2_9_0_, postsinfo0_.title as title3_9_0_, postsinfo0_.user_id as user_id5_9_0_, postsinfo0_.views as views4_9_0_, postimage1_.post_id as post_id1_6_1_, postimage1_.image_l as image_l2_6_1_, postimage1_.image_m as image_m3_6_1_, postimage1_.image_s as image_s4_6_1_ from postsInfo postsinfo0_ left outer join postImage postimage1_ on postsinfo0_.post_id=postimage1_.post_id where postsinfo0_.post_id=?
Hibernate: select postconten0_.post_id as post_id1_5_0_, postconten0_.content as content2_5_0_, postconten0_.subtitle as subtitle3_5_0_ from postContent postconten0_ where postconten0_.post_id=?
Hibernate: select postinside0_.post_id as post_id3_7_0_, postinside0_.image_id as image_id1_7_0_, postinside0_.image_id as image_id1_7_1_, postinside0_.image as image2_7_1_, postinside0_.post_id as post_id3_7_1_ from postInsideImages postinside0_ where postinside0_.post_id=?
Hibernate: select tagspost0_.post_id as post_id1_10_0_, tagspost0_.tag_id as tag_id2_10_0_, tags1_.tag_id as tag_id1_15_1_, tags1_.description as descript2_15_1_, tags1_.name as name3_15_1_ from PostsTags tagspost0_ inner join Tags tags1_ on tagspost0_.tag_id=tags1_.tag_id where tagspost0_.post_id=?
```

What i can do to get a lazy load?

Comment: I would avoid using one to one altogether - they tend to complicate data structure and sometimes create performance problems. You can later seperate the data to different classes with the DTO/DAO system of spring, if you're using it.

Comment: @Kilves, For now i'm using java ee stack, if you suggest how best to organize the data, then I would be glad to any help

Comment: I accepted that @OneToOne never fetches lazily no matter what you do. I ended up using projection.

Comment: @user2215545, if you meant select new project.dto.post(p.id, p.name) from post p, then I have a problem of how to load collections

Answer (score 0):

@Danil Eltsov, that would mean you do another query for that related collection. Lazy load would have generated another query anyway.

Comment: If i need a collection of this posts (n), then i will have to make n request for every post?

Comment: It would mean you make a request for each post. As you can see Hibernate generated 4 queries for you with one of them having a join and I think this is what you are trying to avoid. Related entities with OneToMany which represent a collection will by the default issue an eager load. Hibernate would then issue a query when only you need it. With the projection you do it by hand and therefore you can optimize your queries and avoid hibernated generated queries which you might not need.

Answer (score 0):

You have a design smell in your database. Because you are not sharing the child table PK with parent table PK. One-to-one association always shares the PK. In your case postId of your PostContent class should be mapped by postId of PostsInfo class only. But in PostContent you have separate PK and FK for PostsInfo which should be same for one to one relationship to work, this is advocated by hibernate as well. Because if you have separate FK and PK then there could be multiple PostContent for one PostsInfo.
Please go through the following link because scenario explained in it, is quite similar to that of yours.

https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetoone-relationship-with-jpa-and-hibernate/

Comment: I correctly understand that to receive the content of the post will have to make the 2nd request?(Then i can use inheritance join strategy, but i need 1 request)